# JavaScript database correlation

Tags: javascript, database, correlation

I've been trying to 'correlate' between user picked answers and an object property name so that if the two matches then it will display what  is inside.

My program is a recipe finder that gives back a recipe that consists of the ingredients the user picked. 
my code currently looks like:

**//property are the ingredients and the value are the recipes that contain those ingredients. The map is automatically generated**

```
 ``var map  =   {
"pork" : [recipe1, recipe2, ...],
    "beef" : [],
    "chicken" :[],
}
```

**//this gets the user pick from the dom**

```
var cucumber = specificVegetable[7];
var lemon = specificFruits[0];
```

**//Then this code finds the intersection of the recipe(recipes that use more than one  ingredients)**

```
function intersect(array1, array2) 
{
    return array1.filter(function(n) {
        return array2.indexOf(n) != -1
    });
}

var recipiesWithLemon = map["lemon"];   **// makes the lemon object is map**

var recipiesWithCucumber = map["cucumber"]; **// makes the cucumber object in map**
```

**//Here is where I am stuck**

```
function check(){

    var both = intersect(recipiesWithLemon, recipiesWithCucumber);
    if ( cucumber.checked && lemon.checked){
        for (var stuff in map){
            if(stuff="cucumber" &&  stuff="lemon"){
                return both;
            }
        }
    }


}
check();
```

so basically what I tried to do was I made my intersect and then if user pick is lemon and cucumber then look at the properties in the map object. if the name of the property equals to the exact string then return both. That was the plan but the code does not work  and I'm not sure how to fix it.

My plan is to write code for every possible outcome the user may makes so I need to find the correlation between the user pick and the map which stores the recipe. I realize this is not the most effective way but I'm stumped on how to do it another way.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Im using the open source project [jinqJs](http://www.jinqJs.com) to simplify the process.
I also changed your map to an array of JSON objects. If you must have the map object not as an array, let me know. I will change the sample code.

```js
var map  =  [
    {"pork" : ['recipe1', 'recipe2']},
    {"beef" : ['recipe3', 'recipe4']},
    {"peach" :['recipe5', 'recipe6']},
    {"carrot" :['recipe7', 'recipe8']}
];

var selectedFruit = 'peach';
var selectedVeggie = 'carrot';

var selections = [selectedFruit, selectedVeggie];

var result = jinqJs().from(map).where(function(row){
    for(var f in row) {
      if (selections.indexOf(f) > -1)
        return true;
    }
  
    return false;
}).select();

document.body.innerHTML += '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, null, 2) + '</pre><br><br>';
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/fordth/jinqJs/master/jinqjs.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can only really understand javascript